# kubectl apply -f ngx-dep.yaml error: error validating "ngx-dep.yaml": error validating data:

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ngx-dep3
  labels:
     app: ngx
     type: webservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ngx
    template:
       metadata:
        labels:
          app: ngx
       spec:
        containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:1.8
```

kubectl apply -f ngx-dep.yaml

error: error validating "ngx-dep.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.selector): unknown field "template" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.LabelSelector, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "template" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: The answer is straight forward as mentioned in the error. Remove 2 spaces before template. The hierarchy is changed because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change identation. `template` should be on the same level with  `replicas`, etc

```
spec:
  replicas:
  selector:
  template:
```

Correct yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ngx-dep3
  labels:
     app: ngx
     type: webservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ngx
  template:
     metadata:
      labels:
        app: ngx
     spec:
       containers:
         - name: nginx
           image: nginx:1.8

kubectl apply -f a.yaml
deployment.apps/ngx-dep3 created
```

For mere information and example please refer to [Deployment v1 apps official docs](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#deployment-v1-apps)